# Refused to apply style from "https://cd.shopify.com/xxxxx/assets/compass.css3" because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: css, sass, shopify, stylesheet, compass

I am trying to add a stylesheet on my Shopify store which has @import "compass/css3" in its start and it is not importing the compass/css3, the error I got is:
Refused to apply style from 'https://cdn.shopify.com/xx/xxxx/xxx/assets/compass/css3' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Please help me solve it

when i try to open this file, it shows the error "Sorry, the page you're looking for could not be found."

@import "compass/css3";

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because Shopify is unable to compile your SASS file. According to this article on [Shopify website](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-sass-with-shopify-part-3)

> If you’re letting Shopify compile your Sass
>   file for you, Shopify doesn’t support the @import directive.

A recommended solution for this is to

> If you want to use multiple Sass partials and the @import directive,
>   you will have to compile your Sass locally using an app like
>   [CodeKit](https://codekitapp.com/) or [Prepros](https://prepros.io/), or a task runner like Gulp or Grunt —
>   then sync the files to your theme using [Theme Kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/).